# passing a textbox value as the query string parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, iframe

am looking forward for a solution to the following problem

i do have one i frame in my web page  which refers to the content of yet another page.My problem is that i need change the content of the i frame upon the text box value. so i decided to pass the value of my text box as query string parameter 
 like

```
src="E/Ess/Application_form1.aspx?USER=document .getElementById(TXTCODE).value ">
```

with in my I frame.

but it seems it doesn't work any more.. i have tried java script function  also ?expecting a reasonable solution

Comment: instead of  `document .getElementById(TXTCODE).value` pass the relevent value replacing the value from text box once such solution would be to change src on every text change

Comment: thanks for anwering,but the pblem is that  text box contains the selected row value of a gridview ,so every times user selects it its changing and ned to chage the iframe contents according to it

Comment: can u please give the code?